# Nested Serializer in case of multiple children models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Given the following models

```
class Parent(models.Model)
   type = models.CharField()  # 1 = Child1, 2 = Child2

class Child1(models.Model)
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='child1')

class Child2(models.Model)
   parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='child2')
```

How do I go about setting up a `Parent` serializer which also serializes its children appropriately

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    child = ... # SomeSerializer depending on the `type` field on the parent

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 serializers for each **child** like this:

```
class Child1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Child1
        fields = '__all__'

class Child2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Child2
        fields = '__all__'
```

then make your `Parent` serializer using the `related_name` attribute of your children models and their serializers:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    child1 = Child1Serializer(choice_set='child1')
    child2 = Child2Serializer(choice_set='child2')

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: could do that but I want it to be under the same key.

Comment: what do you mean 'under the same key'?

Comment: instead a having a key for each model `child1`, `child2`, I'd like to have it under just one key called `child`

Comment: well in that case I'm pretty sure it would be better to have just one `Child` model in your models and include nullable fields for both `Child1` and `Child2` models in it